# If I delete the source instance of a Google Cloud Machine Image will it affect the machine image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a VM from a machine image. I upgraded the VM and have created a machine image of that VM. I want to delete my original VM and VM Image. Does deleting the source instance of a VM affect Machine images at all?

Comment: Add more details. If you have created a VM and then created a new image, you can delete both without affecting the original image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer to your question

**Does deleting the source instance of a VM affect Machine images at all?**

→ I tried to simulate in my environment, I have a one VM instance centos OS with two machine images

[image]

→ I tried to delete my VM instance (centos-testcase), and verified the machine images if they still existed, yes still existing

[image]

And also from your machine images you can create an instance, you can try in your environment to check the VM instance if all services and applications are working properly.

[image]

VM instances and machine images are independent resources once deployed or created on your Project..